# Dynamically created list's this selector also referring parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <ul id="parent">

 </ul>

 <script>
   var li =$('<li onclick="clicked(this)"/>').appendTo($('#parent'));
   var span=$('<span/>').text('first').appendTo(li);  
   var ul1=$('<ul onclick="clicked(this)"/>').appendTo(li);
   var li1=$('<ul onclick="clicked(this)"/>').appendTo(ul1);
   var span1=$('<span/>').text('second').appendTo(li1);   

   function clicked(ref)
   {
      alert($(ref).children('span').text());
   } 
</script>
```

My problem is that when I'm clicking on second the alertbox is poping up 2 times and showing first and second both. But I want only second.

How can I refer only `li1`.

Comment: sounds like you need event.stopPropagation in your code

Comment: can you plz tell me how can i do that?

Comment: This happens because the click event bubbles up, so you get the alert for the element that was clicked, in your example, the inner li (alerts second) and as the events bubbles up it is caught by the outer li and alerts again (first). What exactly is it that you need to do on click? why not handle the click on the spans instead?

Comment: event.stopPropagation did the trick for me. thanks buddy. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're adding `li1` as a child to another li. I don't know if that's what you want but you shouldn't do that. That's also why you get two alerts. Both onclick handlers are triggered.

Comment: sorry copied the wrong code. i made some edits. please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make change like this

```
 var li1 =$('<li onclick="clicked(this)"/>').appendTo($('#parent'));
```

Append to Parent element  `<ul id="parent">`

HTH

Comment: actually i am trying to design a try like structure. i have all the data in JSON and using for loop trying to append ul to li.

Comment: You mean "tree" structure?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sample page or fiddle so we can see what output are you trying to do? 
I think you should rewrite your code into something like this:

```
$('<li>')
    .appendTo($('#parent'))
    .click(function(){
     clicked($(this));
    }).append(
        $('span').text('first')
     );

  function clicked(ref)
     {
         alert(ref.text());
     }
```

Anyway it seems that you are appending an LI into another li, you should append it to the parent ul

Comment: actually i am trying to design a try like structure. i have all the data in JSON and using for loop trying to append ul to li.

Comment: yes actually you can use this code. I use this mostly when I'm fetching a data from JSON using a loop like $.each. Here it will create a list object and will append to parent on every loop